# Opening a new terminal window from so x application

Tags: macos, terminal

I have a Mac OS X project (a game using SDL), and for debugging purposes when not running in xcode, I'd like to open up a terminal window that I can send text to and get line input from the user.

Is there a quick way to do this that doesn't involve creating a custom window (which is slightly problematic since the game uses SDL and I don't directly create windows)?

Opening up the standard OS X terminal would be fine, or even connecting to a separate terminal process and then sending output and reading input would also be OK.

The one criteria is that it needs to work when the application is run outside of xcode, or even on machines that don't have xcode installed.

I've spent the last few hours trying to Google this, but my searches are all returning unhelpful results. I'm clearing not seaching on the right keywords.

Thanks.

Comment: I've updated the answer, btw run terminal or sth similar is also possibly, but it needs more coding

Answer (score 0):

Actually every app has ability to interact with console, your just need to run it in a proper way (from a terminal or console)

1. Locate folder with your application. For XCode you can do it in a "Project Navigator" folder "Products", then for your app in context menu press "Show in Finder". For installed application it probably will be in the folder /Applications/. Let it be, for example, /Applications/MyBigProgramm.app.
2. Open console or terminal make `cd` to your app folder /Applications/MyBigProgramm.app/Contents/MacOS
3. There will be an executable file of your app.
4. Run it from console. After it stdin and stdout will be linked to your app.
5. Work with stdin and stdout as you want.

**UPD 1**

A bit of automation.

1. Create applescript with the following content:

   tell application "Terminal" set currentTab to do script 
   ("/Applications/MyBigProgramm.app/Contents/MacOS/MyBigProgramm")
   end tell
2. Save your applescript either as app or script.
3. Run your base application ("MyBigProgramm") by starting your applescript.
4. Work with stdin and stdout as you want within your base application.
5. Watch output in the terminal, type sth in the terminal as input to your base application.

Comment: I need the application to be launched from the icon, and my users might no be savvy enough to open up the package contents to launch it. I was hoping there was a way to connect to another running process.

Comment: @RogerGilbrat it is possible to do so I'll try to update my answer later